# Some more performance and optimization questions... (Local vs. class variables & iterative vs. recursive tree insertion/lookup operations)

Tags: c#, memory, garbage-collection

Good night,

I have two little questions that may seem silly but which are very important for some implementation decisions I need to make right now...

1) Can it be profitable in terms of performance to declare "work variables" of functions called several hundred times as (private) class variables instead of instantiating them in each call (to avoid several unnecessary allocations and consequentely memory pressure and more GC exections)? Does it make any difference in terms of performance?

2) Are there any significant performance gains by coding tree insertion/lookup using iterative functions instead of recursive ones? In this particular case, a lookup can take up to 160000 recursive calls, as many as the nodes of the tree (as insertions also can), so I thought about implementing these functions as iterative, instead of recursive ones.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) It *can be* profitable to declare your working objects as private class variables, but not as often as you might think.  There are several things you have to consider.

First, using private class variables makes your class inherently not thread-safe.  Unless you use thread local storage, which comes with its own performance issues.

It often turns out that re-using an object is more expensive than allocating a new one.  For example, clearing a Hashset or List is often much more expensive than allocating a new one and letting the garbage collector take care of getting rid of it when you're done.

A private class variable remains "in scope" as long as the class instance is in scope.  This can be a problem if you forget to clear it (i.e. set it to `null` or clear the collection) because anything that the private variable references will not be garbage collected.  Using private variables in this way eliminates much of the benefit you gain by having a garbage collector.

The .NET memory manager is very well optimized for short-lived objects.  I've found very few situations in which it makes sense to promote a method-level object out to class scope in order to avoid memory allocation and garbage collector overhead.

I'll echo the advice given by @dtb:  use a profiler to find bottlenecks and identify potential optimization opportunities.  Otherwise you're just poking around in the dark and your "optimization" will likely have a detrimental effect on performance.

Answer (score 2):

1) Variables aren't garbage collected. Objects are. Always declare your variables at the right scope. Use a profiler to find bottlenecks and to evaluate optimizations before applying them. Don't prematurely give up maintainability for speed.

2) Likely. Use a profiler.